# Как сверстать блок с текстом и отдельным элементом

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как выровнять текст по центру не учитывая `img`? Я предпринимал свои попытки реализации идеи на `flex`, но у меня не получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно прочитать про свойство `position`, с помощью него можно создать родительский элемент (в нашем случае `.wrapper`) и внутри него передвигать другие элементы.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Gilroy, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #009a24;
  font-family: Gilroy, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

.main,
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 630px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Приведи друга</h1>
    <h2>Скидка на эвакуацию 30%</h2>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4egJj5c.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну сделал максимально приближенно, стили подкрутите сами.

Comment: Если всё же принципиально нужно flex-ом это всё сделать, напишите. Хотя я бы рекомендовал это делать так.

Comment: Желательно, чтобы элемент был адаптивным.

Comment: @cMeTaHKuH к блоку `.main` можно приписать `flex-shrink`, а к тексту и иконке можно сделать медиа-запросы (`@media`) для уменьшения или увеличивания. Свойство `position` будет зависеть от родителя, тоесть "отодвигаться" от него

Comment: Спасибо за советы, попробую реализовать